# How to use CTE to do recursive for previous row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a problem which I believe can be solve using the CTE.

I create sql query shown below :

```
with CTE as
(
SELECT Distinct T.testType as name,'tmpRequirement_TestType_Canvas' as template,'n/a' as layout,
0 as x,0 as y,'855' as width,'42' as height,
T.id,T.testType FROM [dbo].[tProperty] P
INNER JOIN tTest_Type T 
on P.tTest_Type_id = T.id)

select * from CTE
```

I got the results like below:
[image]

What I would like to get is like shown below :
[image]

Basically I would like to have 'y' to be increment by 50 for each row. Is there any way for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need an `order` to add 50 to each record.

Answer (score 1):

You need an ordering, but `row_number()` will do this:

```
select . . .,
       50 * row_number() over (order by ?) as y
from cte;
```

`?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

As your sample from above:

This will start from 0 and Add 50:

```
select setNumber from 
(select setNumber from
(select 50 * ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) as setNumber from yourTableOrCTE) as a
union all
select 0) as a order by setNumber
```

Comment: you can change `id` to your own field.